# How does an unattended Windows install decide which partition to install to?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, iso-image, unattended

After doing research, I've decided I want to make a unattended, pre-configured Windows 10 ISO for myself, but given I have two partitions (one SSD for the OS, one HDD high capacity low speed storage), I want to make sure this unattended Win10 image doesn't install on my HDD. Is this even possible, and if so. how do I make sure this happens to the correct drive or partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk handling for unattended.xml is defined by the
[DiskConfiguration clause](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-setup-diskconfiguration)
which you define.

For more detailed information, see the articles:

- [Unattended Windows Setup Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/)
- [Create media for automated unattended install of Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/96683-create-media-automated-unattended-install-windows-10-a.html)
- [Windows Answer File Generator](https://www.windowsafg.com/index.html)

Comment: I'm surprised at your link only answer harry.

Comment: @Moab: A Microsoft link, to enable studying the subject. There is not one answer here.

Comment: Should be a comment not an answer

Comment: @Moab: This should help solve the user's dilemma, although from his lack of response it seems that it's already solved.

Comment: You're correct. It's *mostly* solved my issue. I have not marked it correct, I apologise.